# Detect \ using regex in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have loaded a list of 80+ text documents. In each document, there are multiple places where I want to pull information in the following pattern: \\\text\\\. Here I want "text", but do not know how to handle the "\" character in R.

For example, if I try to load a small example as a test I get the following error:

```
string <- "\\\Ok; front of house rude!\\\"
Error: '\O' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\\\O"
```

If I change `string` to `"\\\\OK; front of house!\\\\"` then I can proceed with a test example, but remember in the loaded text docs, the format is \\\text\\\.

I'm trying to grab the text in between and I get the following error:

```
str_extract_all(string, "(?<=\\).*(?=\\)")

Error in stri_extract_all_regex(string, pattern, simplify = simplify,  : 
Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)
```

Just to show that the lookbehind-lookahead combo works:

```
str_extract_all(string, "(?<=\\;).*(?=\\!)")

[[1]]
[1] " front of house rude"
```

EDIT:

Again, take the following string and apply `str_replace_all`:

```
string <- "\\\\Ok; front of house rude!\\\\"
str_replace_all(string, "\\+", "REPLACE_ME")

# returns the original string rather than replacing the pattern
[1] "\\\\Ok; front of house rude!\\\\"
```

Comment: I agree that seem like a duplicate: However, if I use the following expression: `str_replace_all(string, "\\+", "REPLACE_ME")` it returns

Comment: cont'd: `"\\\\Ok; front of house rude!\\\\"`

Comment: My understanding would be to find all "\" and replace them with "REPLACE_ME".